# Selecting a non-tag element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-tag

I have the multiple tags as mentioned below in my HTML. Note the square brackets like BBcode.

```
[oembed]http://rich-media.url[/oembed]
```

I need to get the value of URL using jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hxa4m8Ld/1/

```
var content = $('#mytags').text();
var currIndex = 0;
while(currIndex < content.length){
    var stIndex = content.indexOf("[oembed]",currIndex);
  var edIndex = content.indexOf("[/oembed]",stIndex);
  if(stIndex > -1 && edIndex> -1){
    var url = content.substring(stIndex+8,edIndex);
    currIndex = edIndex+9;
    console.log(url);
  }
  else
  {
    currIndex = content.length;
  }
}
```

I used simple javascript string functions to fetch the required urls. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to retrieve the content between the braces, something like this:

```
var content = '[oembed]http://rich-media.url[/oembed]';
var matches = /\[.+\](.+)\[.+\]/g.exec(content);
console.log(matches[1]); // = 'http://rich-media.url'
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. I tried your code, it works but only for first match. I have setup a fiddle here with sample HTML https://jsfiddle.net/hxa4m8Ld/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var content = $('#mytags').html();
var matches = /\[.+\](.+)\[.+\]/g.exec(content);

content.replace(/\[.+\](.+)\[.+\]/g, function(m, key, value){

      //this is url
      console.log(key);

});
```